# Most efficient way to make a slot machine animation where each item stops spinning at a certain time

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, animation

I have a slot machine with the three columns. Three fruits will spin together and then the first will stop, then the second and finally the third. I have used tkinter and this function is in a class.

```
def animate(self):
    chosen_random_fruits = []
    x_positions = [0.24, 0.43, 0.62]
    for no_of_fruits_spinning in range(3, 0, -1):
        for _ in range(100):
            random_fruits = [random.choice(self.weighted_fruits) for _ in range(no_of_fruits_spinning)]
            for random_fruit, x_pos in zip(random_fruits, x_positions):
                Label(image=self.fruits[random_fruit].image, bg="white").place(relx=x_pos, y=100)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            self.root.update()
        chosen_random_fruits.append(random_fruits[0])
        x_positions = x_positions[1:]
    return chosen_random_fruits
```

The dictionary self.fruits assigns a namedtuple (including an image) for each of the fruits. x_positions is simply to place the fruits in the correct place. Is there a more efficient or simpler way to do this than the way I have implemented?

Comment: Well, the most efficient way would not involve using Tkinter in the first place, but who cares? As long as you're not doing anything algorithmically stupid, and can do 60fps without dropping frames or overheating the CPU, why is "most efficient way" even marginally relevant?

Comment: Anyway, there's almost never a reason to `sleep` inside a Tkinter (or other GUI) app. Instead of writing a function that takes a long time to run, and calls `update` every 10ms, just write a function that does one step of the loop, calls `after` to ask Tkinter to schedule the rest of the code and returns to the event loop. This can sometimes be more complicated (it requires turning your logic "inside out" from the sequential flow), but it will mean smoother running, fewer opportunities for accidentally freezing up your GUI, and, yes, usually even more efficiency.

Comment: Also, instead of placing a new label over the old one, you probably want to remember the existing labels, and re-`config` the appropriate one with the new image. If you don't want to do that, you should at least destroy the old labels instead of just hiding them. Otherwise, you end up with an extra 297 widgets that Tkinter has to keep track of that the user isn't seeing or interacting with.

Comment: The second one should be fixed, but the first one… well, as long as you can do all the work in a tiny fraction of 10ms, and there's no way you can end up recursively back inside this function at the same time (e.g., you haven't left the slot machine arm enabled), that should work just fine. Although if you're going to stick with that design, you probably want an update _before_ the sleep, so the changes show up instantly instead of 10ms late, which could be noticeable at the edge of subconscious perception.